# How to give today's date in CLI Unix while submitting a command?

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to run a particular shell script in UNIX. This shell script triggers a sqoop query, hive import query.

While submitting this query I have framed it I a way such as **./Type1.sh JOB_NAME TODAY'S_DATE**

If I am running it manually I'll be able to provide today's date. But all my jobs are going to be scheduled in oozie and when I use **date +'%Y-%m-%d'** , only the string **date** is being considered and not the actual today's date.

Is there a way to pass today's date directly in the command line while submitting a job? Kindly help.

Comment: Unrelated: `%F` is a shortcut for `%Y-%m-%d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution): `./Type1.sh JOB_NAME "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"`